# vigor 2960 won't start after firmware upgrade

Tags: local-area-network, vigor

I tried to upgrade the firmware of a Vigor 2960 through their interface. Everything was working fine until the reboot.

The upgrade was from 1.0.7.0 to 1.0.8.2.

It rebooted for a while and now I can't see the router page even directly connected through LAN. It doesn't do anything. I tried this update after having issues with my fiber connection, it's 300Mb/s and it just wasn't working on pppoe.